# Why does GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION 3.3 render slower than 2.0?

Tags: c, opengl, glfw, opengl-3

I have the following code:

```
#include <glad/glad.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

#define GLFW_INCLUDE_NONE

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static void error_callback(int error, const char *description)
{
    printf("Error: %s\n", description);
}

int main()
{
    glfwInit();

    glfwSetErrorCallback(error_callback);

    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 2);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 0);

    GLFWwindow *window = glfwCreateWindow(800, 600, "Learn OpenGL", NULL, NULL);

    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
    if (!gladLoadGLLoader((GLADloadproc)glfwGetProcAddress))
    {
        printf("Failed to initialize GLAD. Fatal error.\n");
        return -1;
    }
    glfwSwapInterval(1);

    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {

        int width, height;

        glfwGetFramebufferSize(window, &width, &height);

        glViewport(0, 0, width, height);

        glClearColor(0.0f, 0.5f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        glfwPollEvents();
    }

    glfwDestroyWindow(window);

    glfwTerminate();

    return 0;
}
```

When the code is set the way it is above, with GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION set to 2.0, it works pretty well. When I resize the window, as soon as I stop resizing, it renders the new portion. However, when I set the version to 3.3 (which is the version I want to use) it lags a bit in spreading the blue across the whole window (even after I have stopped resizing it), as can be seen here: (I'm running Windows by the way)

[image]

This does not happen when the version is 2.0. Why is this, and how can I get it so it renders in 3.3 as well as it does in 2.0?

When I set `GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE` to `GLFW_OPENGL_COMPAT_PROFILE` it works in 3.3 just like in 2.0 but on `GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE` (which is what I want to use) it doesn't. How do I fix it so it works in `CORE_PROFILE`?

(I suspect GLFW is using some sort of deprecated function... I don't know. I'm using glfw3, so shouldn't it not have any deprecated functions though?)

Comment: Experiment with `glfwSetFramebufferSizeCallback` and `glfwSetWindowRefreshCallback` - window resize events don't behave like other events on some platforms. Furthermore, `glWaitEvents` can be used in this approach, rather than polling.

Comment: @BrettHale: Did you mean [`glfwWaitEvents()`](https://www.glfw.org/docs/3.3/group__window.html#ga554e37d781f0a997656c26b2c56c835e)?

Comment: @BrettHale `glfwWaitEvents()`  only made it slower.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what worked for me. I have an Intel UHD Graphics 620 GPU, and I updated my driver, and now it works.

Old driver version was 24.something, new driver version is 30.0.101.1660.